# O que aconteceu com o avatar do usuário Comunidade?

Tags: bug, status-pronto

Hoje percebi que o avatar do [usuário Comunidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/comunidade) mudou, tendo ele recebido um gravatar gerado automaticamente:

[image: gravatar novo]

Antigamente, o avatar utilizado era o logotipo da SE:

[image: avatar antigo]

O que aconteceu?

Comment: Ué rs, aqui ele ainda aparece assim: https://i.stack.imgur.com/At98q.png

Comment: Sera que não tem alguma relação? Existem usuários aqui na rede que mesmo eu acreditando haver uma imagem no perfil, eu não consigo enxerga-la, tipo o @diegofm... Você mesmo é um deles: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TWQ9.png

Comment: @MarceloBonifacio Tente ver o avatar de 32 x 32 pixels que aparece na listagem de perguntas tanto do site principal quanto do meta.

Comment: @MarceloBonifacio Que avatar você vê nesse link? http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/5173/1

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xp1Gi.png desse link: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/359/14262
Esse que mandou: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uJLU.png

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio Bem, o que vejo nesses casos é o gravatar verde-amarelado que postei.

Comment: A titulo de curiosidade: https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a007be5a61f6aa8f3e85ae2fc18dd66e?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG aparece isso? https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWU9n.png

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio Para mim, não. Vejo o gravatar verde-amarelado. Dei um Ctrl+F5 no meu navegador e nada mudou.

Comment: Aqui tá normal em todos os lugares e tamanhos. Pode ter sido alguma pequena instabilidade no sistema e o ícone alternativo ter sido servido (e ficado em algum cache pelo caminho). O link para o icone é https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a007be5a61f6aa8f3e85ae2fc18dd66e - Qual o URL para o ícone que você mencionou?

Comment: @Bacco O link para mim é esse: https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a007be5a61f6aa8f3e85ae2fc18dd66e?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG

Comment: é, é o mesmo (tirando as configurações de exibição). Aqui aparece o icone padrão. Experimente por alguma alteração no final tipo &dummy=23732839 só pra contornar o cache

Comment: @Bacco Acrescentando o `&dummy=23732839` veio o ícone correto. Ou seja, deve ter dado algum problema no gravatar que já foi arrumado e tive o azar de manter cacheado o ícone errado.